# MongoDB RESTful API with Flask on AWS

Tags: mongodb, rest, amazon-ec2

I have an AWS EC2 instance with Ubuntu 14.04, and have installed and populated a MongoDB service on this instance. My objective is to have an endpoint to CRUD with data present inside this MongoDB. I followed all the steps given in this tutorial here: http://www.bogotobogo.com/python/MongoDB_PyMongo/python_MongoDB_RESTAPI_with_Flask.php but this tutorial only teaches how to do this on localhost.

Can somebody help me with the modifications I have to make to make sure this code works for AWS EC2 instance as well?

For the EC2, I have given HTTPS and HTTP inbound access from 0.0.0.0/0 on top of SSH access.

Thanks!

Comment: You might also needs to open other ports used by mongodb for inbound connections in security group

Comment: @Ashan thank you. I forgot to mention that I already had opened everything (not too secure a case, but in my defense I was in the learning process.)

But I solved this last night. So the code in the hyperlink is perfect by itself. Only thing that needed to be changed is add `'host=0.0.0.0'` inside `app.run()`